# WordPress - functions.php will not register my JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to register my JavaScript file in my `function.php` file. But when I add in the function to load the JavaScript file, nothing happens. When I go into dev tools and inspect it on the browser, it isn't appearing there either. (I am working locally)

Here is my PHP code:

```
function add_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts');
```

This is at the bottom of my function.php file, and the file, scripts.js is located in the js folder in my theme folder.

I should at least be seeing this load when i inspect the webpage with my dev tools, but it's not appearing. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Try changing the handle `scripts` (first parameter) to something a little less generic (eg. `my_theme_name_main_script`) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `/` before js path folder. Add follows -

```
function add_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('your_scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'script-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20181207',true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', 12 );
```

**This method is tested and working**

Answer (score 0):

Just missed out with the '/' in file path. Please be careful with the `handle` i.e `script`. Just copy the code and replace your one.

```
function add_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts');
```

Answer (score 0):

please make sure your id is unique.
first param in wp_enqueue_script.